# Postgres sql dump import error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm facing a issue while importing the dump in my system, i'm getting the error as

> " Error: syntax error at or near "`"   LOCK TABLES`DB_NAME` WRITE;"

and exiting with `"out of memory"`

We had taken back-up from Suse linux and trying to import in  `Cent OS 6.3`.

Any suggestion to fix this issue.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Are you using a command like `psql dbname < dumpfile.sql` to do the import?

Comment: Yes i'm using that command to import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LOCK TABLES dname WRITE` is not a valid PostgreSQL statement. It's a MySQL statement. You can't just take a MySQL dump and restore it to Postgres. You'll need to convert it either manually or find some kind of converter script.